# Map functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

```
var data = [{
  id: 22,
  cno: 1,
  username: 'white',
  name: 'New Complaint',
  stype: null,
  cname: 'ff',
  product: 'ff',
}];

var finalData = data.map(x => {
  return ({ cno: x.cno + 1 })
});
console.log(finalData); // output [ { cno: 2} ]
```

My expected output i need this as object not as Array, is it possible to do using map?

Finally i need `{ cno : 2}`

Comment: Not using `map` alone. [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) always returns an array. If your array always only has one element you can just use `[0]` to access it, but you really shouldn't be using map in that case.

Comment: how to get that as a object

Comment: you can use `reduce`

Comment: Does your `data` array always contain exactly one element?

Comment: @Paulpro yes one element

Comment: @GANESHPANDIYAN whats wrong with `console.log(finalData[0]);`?

Comment: i m sending this in front end as for my project model i need it as one object, i dont want to access as [0].

Comment: [finalData] = data;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're just trying to operate on a single object you shouldn't use map at all. You should use something like:

```
var finalData = { cno: data[ 0 ].cno + 1 };
```

Example:

```js
var data = [{
  id: 22,
  cno: 1,
  username: 'white',
  name: 'New Complaint',
  stype: null,
  cname: 'ff',
  product: 'ff',
}];

var finalData = { cno: data[ 0 ].cno + 1 };

console.log( finalData );
```

Comment: But if going with this approach make sure your `data` is never an empty array(i.e always has atleast one element) or this will throw an error.

Comment: @AyushGupta Agreed, this answer works under an assumption that the OP stated in the comments on his question: that the array always has exactly one element.

Comment: @Yep, but a check is never a bad thing. Remember Murphy's Law: *whatever can go wrong, will go wrong.*

Answer (score 2):

you can use `reduce` instead of `map`. `map` actually return an `array`. using reduce you can get the desired result.

```js
var data = [{
  id: 22,
  cno: 1,
  username: 'white',
  name: 'New Complaint',
  stype: null,
  cname: 'ff',
  product: 'ff',
}];

var finalData = data.reduce((acc, elem, index) => {
  acc.cno = elem.cno + 1 
  return acc
}, {});
console.log(finalData); // output { cno: 2}
```

Comment: Reduce is useful for reducing an array to a single value. In this case the OP mentioned (in comments) that their `data` array always has exactly one element, so it has no reason to actually be an array in the first place, or be operated on like an array. It's much simpler to just access the object using `data[ 0 ]` in this case.

Comment: @Paulpro yes.but i tried more general way to answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is using ES6 destructuring (`[data] = data;`) as in the following example:

```js
var data = [{
  id: 22,
  cno: 1,
  username: 'white',
  name: 'New Complaint',
  stype: null,
  cname: 'ff',
  product: 'ff',
}];

[data] = data; // data is now the nested object
console.log(data); // Return data as object

// After that, you can modify data however you want
data.cno += 1;
console.log(data); // Return updated data as object
```